# Are there any corporate antivirus solutions that are not license based?

Tags: windows, licensing, anti-virus

Does anyone know of any corporate anti-virus solutions available for a Windows environment that is not license based?  Everything I have ever seen is either client or user license based, plus the management software.

I'm thinking along the lines of Barracuda Networks business model for their products, where you buy the product based on needed resources and not user or client count.

Just wondering if this business model in the antivirus world even exists. If so, are they good products?  Thanks.

Comment: how are resources different from clients? your question is confusing, any service you purchase is going to be equivalent. You can look at products that protect the edge perhaps but that doesn't help you when someone brings something on the inside physically.

Comment: Not that I've seen. Some products used to offer a 'site license', but I haven't seen those in several years. Everyone has since gone to some variation of seat-count for scaling the price.

Comment: To put it simply, buying a product that does not require additional licenses each time a client or user is added.  You pay one price for the software, maybe pay a yearly subscription fee to get the updates, and then as long as the software can handle the number of clients you throw at it then there are no more additional costs to you.

Comment: It's unlikely. The business model of A/V vendors is providing the same software to all size of organisation, so they have to charge for it on a per-seat basis.   The alternative model, whereby you pay different, fixed fees for varying feature sets (Student/Pro/Enterprise) for instance can't apply, since no-one would ever buy a 'basic' level A/V product :)

Answer (score 1):

[You can try out ClamWin which is the Windows version of ClamAV. It is open source and the license (GPL) allows unlimited redistribution and use.](http://www.clamwin.com/)

I'm not sure if it's made for enterprise (there doesn't seem to be any management software for multiple computers).

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) is free as long as you have a valid Windows licence.

Comment: Not for more than 10 users it isn't.

Comment: @Tom true, sorry, one day I will remember all the articles of all the licenses I have accepted.

Comment: I've been looking at this recently at work.

Comment: This would be my preference, but I'm 99% sure it's not licensed for corporate use.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that I've seen no.

F-Prot is cheap enough if money really is an issue, but anything I'm aware of is usually based off node count or "protected user" count.

The best option is, if possible, to play the vendors you're interested in off against one another and get the best pricing you can for a product you'd work with.

MSE is free but for small businesses so read the EULA very carefully as if you're using the word "corporate" it suggests you're not a small business.